# How does a control know that it's being added to form?

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I have a modified control (winforms) (let's say a simple label).
How can this label know that it's being added to another control (form, groupbox..)

Which type of event can I add ?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What do you want to achieve with this? What's your goal?

Comment: @Matias Well for exemple when this control get' sur added to a form its name becomes "Hello"

Comment: @Tweee I wouldn't be able to produce a sample code now, but you should do this with data-binding instead of with controls

Comment: Check [Parent Changed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.parentchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event, [`OnParentChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onparentchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) method and [`Parent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.parent(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Comment: Thanks just found out :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer : Added ParentChanged Event to UserControl